# Bareword "NUMBER" not allowed while "strict subs" in use

Tags: perl, syntax

the issue code:

```
{
    port_id   => { type => SCALAR },
    ipv4_addr => { type => SCALAR },
    gateway   => { type => SCALAR },
    netmask   => { type => SCALAR },
    vlan_id   => { type => NUMBER, optional => 1 },
}
```

I used 'use strict;' in my pm file, and based on the error info "Bareword "NUMBER" not allowed while "strict subs" in use", i know i need to add '' for types, such as 'NUMBER'. But before there is no NUMBER type in my code, and i did not add '' for these types, and it has not reported any errors. 
So i want to know why NUMBER is special?

Answer (score 5):

Without `use strict 'subs';`, identifiers that have no other grammatical meaning are treated as string literals that produce themselves when evaluated. That's very error-prone (because it easily leads to code doing one thing when doing another is expected), so we all use `use strict 'subs';` in our code to rid us of this mis-feature.

If you want to create an operator that produces the string `NUMBER` or `SCALAR` when using `use strict 'subs';`, you'll need to use something other than `NUMBER` and `SCALAR`. As you mentioned, you could use `'NUMBER'` and `'SCALAR'`.

The other possibility is that `NUMBER` is supposed to be the name of a constant, but that you forgot to declare/import the constant. This is exactly the type of error that `use strict 'subs';` is supposed to catch.